# calling activity from webview with @JavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm stuck on my project and requesting your help! 
I'm trying to call an Activity(BarcodeScannerActivity.java) from webview in MainActivity.java with button click using javascript call. I think I messed up with parameters somewhere... I'm not sure where I've made mistake, I just copied and modified the codes from blogs and stackoverflow.

I'm having this error in my Android Studio logcat:

> [INFO:CONSOLE(315)] "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.", source: http:// .........

this is my server side html:

```
 <input type="button" value="Scanner" id="BtnScan" class="btn_dark" onclick="callActivity();" /> 
<script>
  function callActivity() {
    Android.openBarcodeScanner();
  }
</script>
```

this is my MainActivity.java containing webview:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        //getActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebview);
        MainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //-- add javascript listener
        MainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        MainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        MainWebView.loadUrl(WebViewURL);
    }

..skipped for brevity..

public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openBarcodeScanner(String str) {
            Intent barcodeScanIntent = new Intent(mContext, BarcodeScannerActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(barcodeScanIntent);
        }
}
```

and last, the BarcodeScannerActivity.java that wants to be called:

```
public class BarcodeScannerActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//    private static final  R = ;
    // use a compound button so either checkbox or switch widgets work.
    private CompoundButton autoFocus;
    private CompoundButton useFlash;
    private TextView statusMessage;
    private TextView barcodeValue;

    private static final int RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE = 9001;
    private static final String TAG = "BarcodeMain";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.barcode_scanner);

        statusMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_message);
        barcodeValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barcode_value);

        autoFocus = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.auto_focus);
        useFlash = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.use_flash);

        findViewById(R.id.read_barcode).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.read_barcode) {
            // launch barcode activity.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BarcodeCaptureActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.AutoFocus, autoFocus.isChecked());
            intent.putExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.UseFlash, useFlash.isChecked());

            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
                    statusMessage.setText(R.string.barcode_success);
                    barcodeValue.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Barcode read: " + barcode.displayValue);
                } else {
                    statusMessage.setText(R.string.barcode_failure);
                    Log.d(TAG, "No barcode captured, intent data is null");
                }
            } else {
                statusMessage.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.barcode_error),
                        CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(resultCode)));
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

and one last question is, would this javascript code work in my situation, too?
or do I need to modify a bit?

```
function  callActivity(){

            if(window.android){

                console.info("android");

                 window.android.openBarcodeScanner(number.value);           

            }

            else{

                console.info("web");

                document.form.submit();

            }

        }

    }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your interface takes a string as a parameter:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void openBarcodeScanner(String str) {
```

But your invocation doesn't pass any parameters:

```
Android.openBarcodeScanner();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Doug! I want to pass scanned barcode data (ex: 078742353098) to <input> button from client side. what parameter should I write between parenthesis?? is it Android.openBarcodeScanner(barcode.displayValue); ?

Comment: Whatever string you want to send from the javascript side to the java side, sure.  In any event, your invocation should match the definition both in type and number of parameters.